# Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to share my application url on facebook. But while sharing this some of the urls are working rest of them are throwing "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped" error.

Working URL:

[working](http://54.165.121.59:9999/livetv/etc-bollywood-ab-tak-slash-songs-2015-02-03-10-30-00)

Error URL:

[not working](http://54.165.121.59:9999/livetv/zoom-zoomit-playlist-2015-02-03-11-30-00)

What could be the issue in this?

Comment: It sounds like the URL's themselves are fine but Facebook is having proplems connecting and retrieving the content from your servers

Comment: @Matt is there any solution to resolve this?